# Direct Message to online users in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor

In a chat application, I want to be able to send messages to two users directly if there are online. I'm using `mizzao:user-status` to detect if they are online or not. Let's imagine 2 users Tom and Sam. So both are online and using the application. Now when Tom sends a mesaage to Sam and vice-versa, I want to send the message directly to Sam without first storing it in MongoDB through Web Sockets. Meteor Streams seemed like a viable option, but here's the problem. Let's say 1000 people are using the app all at once. Now some people can send only their `friends` messages. How do I ensure security so Sam can't edit some source files and read everyone's messages going through the wire.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever solve this, I'm dealing with the exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

When I was doing my chat app I didn't use any streams, since Meteor is reactive I just stored all messages in a Collection, and `find()` was returning data, no packages were needed.
If I wanted to send data to users, I simply `fetch()` users who are online(with `mizzao:user-status` aswell), and then sent message to all of them using `.forEach`

Comment: I want to delete all the messages when the user goes offline. Instead of storing it in MongoDB, a local collection would make stuff much easier. Thoughts?

Comment: It's a bit around but you can delete messages when person is closing tab with `hooks` package, speciffically `Hooks.onCloseSession`

Comment: But let's say (refering to the example) Sam logs off and messages get deleted. Now if Tom is viewing those messages he would see the msgs disappear suddenly. Ideally, msg from Tom's side will disappear when he logs out. Seems too complicated with normal Collections

Comment: You can make flags `visibleToUserOne`, `visibleToUserTwo` and update it instead of deleting it

Comment: Instead of storing them in a collection, how about you put them in a Session variable?  Each person can have their own copy.  This way, refreshing or leaving the app will cause the Session to get killed, but the variable can still be treated as "reactive".  Or, if you want to use Collections, do a "soft delete" buy storing a "read_by" array to indicate that a particular person already read the message.